# Woocommerce in a subdirectory

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a computer repairs website and i would like to sell refurbished stock from my suppliers on it, i do not want to waste time in the design aspect of the shop so would like to use another theme which i've found, is it possible to have the shop in a sub directory? The shop will be /shop

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can install another woocommerce site in /shop folder.
Just make sure that the shop url on your main site is not /shop

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to a sub directory could work, yes, though I'd argue that it's a little more trouble than it's worth. For one, it might be a bit of a jarring change for your customers if the design is different, and for two I've had mixed results adding things into a subdirectory.

If you do choose to keep the sites separate, then I'd suggest creating a subdomain like `shop.example.com`. You could put a shop folder in the same level as your main site and direct it there. That will prevent any issues you may have if you create a page with the slug "Shop" in your regular store.